# Convert a shapefile to GeoJSON with PHP

Tags: geojson, php

Is there a method in PHP to covert a shapefile to GeoJSON? I need to upload shapefile and load it into a PostgreSQL table. I tried PHP exec(), but it didn't work.

Comment: load the shapefile into postgis and use ST_AsGeoJSON http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html for GeoJSON creation

Answer (score 2):

PHP `exec()` should work, what error do you get? And what commands/utilities are you using to convert?

For example with ogr2ogr:

```
$command = "/usr/bin/ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.shp";
exec($command);
```

You should use [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) if any of these params are coming from user input

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this late answer just as a service for the community, since this is one of the questions that pop up when looking for *"converting ESRI Shapefiles to GeoJSON with PHP"*.

My [PHP Shapefile](https://github.com/gasparesganga/php-shapefile) library can read and write any ESRI Shapefile and convert it natively from/to **WKT** and **GeoJSON**.

It is a free, open source, native PHP library, does not require any third party dependency or *evil* `eval()` and it is actively maintained.